# How to save the first N rows of a table in R into a file?

Tags: r, data-structures

I have a table data structure that contains 10000 rows (using R package). I know how to save the whole object using the function write.table(...); however, I am wondering if there is an easy way to save just the first N rows ( in the same order ) of that table, where N<10000. I am sure I can use a loop to iterate over the first N rows of the table, but an easier predefined function or parameter would always be helpful. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `object[1:N,]` with `write.table ();`